# Eclipse Debug as Web Application Option Missing

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, libgdx

I am following this tutorial: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/09/19/LibGDX-Tutorial-1-Creating-an-initial-project.aspx, but my installation of Eclipse (Kepler) doesn't seem to have a `Debug as Web Application option'.

[image]
I've installed the web tools from Help->Install New Software, but it's still not there. How do I get this option to show up and debug my project as a web application?

Comment: I suspect that the option is not there as a result of me using classic instead of the Java EE version. I'm currently installing what will hopefully be a correct version of Luna.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'Debug As' --> 'Debug on Server' option, I can see it in your snapshot.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work and now the option has disappeared.

Comment: If your application is a dynamic web app and your eclipse is JavaEE version, then you should not be facing such issues. Though I have seen such issues but they are resolved once the project is built properly  / eclipse restarted. Check if you are facing any such issue.